# Javascript not executing immediately?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have a javascript in a form of an extension on my Brave, that is connected to the authotkey commands, when I press a button the script will activate and constantly check for the button on a website, I refresh the website and the button appears, javascript clicks the button... Perfect...

Only sometimes, for no reason what so ever, it wont click it until full page is loaded and its slow to execute, other times it works in 0.1 seconds and clicks the button soon as it appears in the elements, I have tried a million things, even going so far to reinstall Windows, I do not change the code nothing in the code changes, the script sometimes works before site loads really fast, and sometimes waits for the whole page to load before clicking it. (It will usually work for few hours or days and then stop working)

My internet is fiber optics always same Ms and 0 jitter.

ANY TOUGHTS?

Comment: So, you reinstalled Windows because of a Brave extension not waiting to load? Please read [ask], take a [tour], [edit] with a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe: [Window load Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be something on your end.

Sometimes, one element on the page that's getting loaded will take longer to load for reasons that are not under your own control - for example images loaded from a 3rd party source, like ads. This can cause delays in other dependent processes (that includes your script). However,

- if you update your question with reproduction instructions we might be able to determine why, and,
- in hindsight, it does sound like a [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) being delayed, and it might be possible to change the script reference point to be  a [DOMContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) which fires sooner and should be enough for your script to start clicking stuff.

Comment: Yes but command is always the same and the page I do this on always loads the same content, nothing changes, 30 minutes it does not work then it starts for 8 hours randomly for example, and then it stops again after few days for few hours etc.